# PHP web application can't connect mysql installed with Zend Server CE on SuSE Linux 11.4

Tags: php, mysql, zend

I had a running LAMP system.
SUSE 11.4 with Apache 2, MySQL and PHP 5.3

Then I installed Zend Server CE.

Everything is OK, but now I can't connect it to MySQL.

The MySQL Server is running.

If I uninstall Zend server CE and install the "normal" PHP everything is OK!